# how to generate crud in modules folder in yii

Tags: yii

I am try create CRUD Through GII in YII Framework in modules folder .But there one option to change the CRUD path.

Comment: You seem to be missing your first attempt at code

Answer (score 9):

I looked around for this too. Hope this will help.

1. Create a module via Module Generator.
2. Register your module name in the config main.php (modules array)
3. Create a model via Model Generator. Fill in the fields and put this in Model Path : application.modules.[module-name].models
4. Create crud via Crud Generator. Fill in the fields and put this in Model Class: [module-name].models.[model-name]

Sorry the reference is in Indonesian.
[Source](http://arif.suparlan.com/2012/05/10/yii-cara-buat-crud-di-dalam-module-menggunakan-gii)

Answer (score 7):

1. Create a module via Module Generator.
2. Register your module name in the config main.php (modules array)
3. Create a model via Model Generator. Fill in the fields and put this in Model Path : application.modules.[module-name].models
4. Create crud via Crud Generator. Fill in the fields and put this in Model Class: [module-name].models.[model-name]
        add module name in Controller ID :[module-name]/[Controller-name]

Answer (score 4):

- `module-name/user` generates `module-name/UserController.php`.
                      If the application has an `module-name` module enabled,
                      it will generate `UserController` (and other CRUD code)
                      within the module `module-name` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe is useful to create controllers

[image: controller help]

like that you can get it your controller and view inside the module you want. Regarding the models, I am agree with previous answers.

Byee

Answer (score 0):

Model Class: user_access.models.User

Controller ID: user_access/user

Answer (score 0):

> Model Class : application.modules.guestbook.models.Guestbook
>
> Controller ID : guestbook/Default

Note : guestbook is my module name and i created crud directly inside guestbook folder using above path.